# How can I replace column name with the comments given in table's field definition

Tags: php, mysql

I want to change the column name with a descriptive name, like in my table I have a field name "job_title",
I want to replace this heading with "what is your job title", and job_description with "Describe your job description"
For accomplishing this task I can use Aliasing but I want to change the column names dynamically instead of hard code.
I have described these questions in the comments section of the individual field of the table and I am trying to fetch these comments from the database and display comments of the field as the column heading but couldn't accomplish it.
This is my PHP code:

```
    $sql_getcolumns="select * interview_col_comments where table_name ='interview'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql_getcolumns);
    echo "<table>";
     echo "<tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
      {
          echo "<th>".$row[0]."</th>";
      }
```

echo "";
I also tried to find a way in the PhpMyAdmin interface if I labeled column names and retrieve labels using a query in PHP
but didn't find this option in the SQL interface.

Is there another Approach using PHP, or SQL Which I can use to give columns of the table descriptive names?

Comment: spaces in column names - why? What benefit do you feel this will bring?

Comment: _"For accomplishing this task I can use Aliasing but I want to change the column names dynamically instead of hard code"_ - so put the alias names into your query _dynamically_ then, instead of hard-coding them ...

Comment: You can query the `information_schema` to obtain the `column_comment` and `column_name`

Comment: You cannot dynamically set column aliases in an sql query. You need to retrieve the column aliases first, then dynamically **construct** the 2nd query that uses the aliases. However, I'm not sure I would do this on a query level. I would do this on the application level when I display results. I would also not store the display names in field comments, but in a proper config table. It is easier to maintain the aliases this way.

Answer (score 0):

- One approach can be make an array in php like below.

```
<?php  $comment=[
'job_title' => "what is your job title",'job_description'=>"Describe your job description"];
 echo "<th>".$comment[$row[0]]."</th>";
?>'
```

- Another approach can be make a another table with column description in mysql and replace on run time.

> ```
>   id|column_id|description
>    1|job_title|"what is your job title"      
>    2|job_description|"Describe your job description"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called "localization".

There are many ways to do that.

I usually ALSO prefer to keep this information tightly wired to the database I'm working with, so what I did is:

I used the Database Column's Comment field to provide meta-information.
For example, a columns comment can look like this:

```
#required #de=Vertragsnummer #en=Contract_Number #search
```

Now, using the following query, I can retrieve the comments, and build a `ColumnMetadataObject` out of the information using some regex / string operations.

```
SELECT 
    c.`TABLE_NAME`,
    c.`COLUMN_NAME`, 
    c.`COLUMN_COMMENT`, 
    t.`TABLE_COMMENT` 
FROM 
    information_schema.columns c left join 
    information_schema.TABLES t ON 
    c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME and 
    c.TABLE_SCHEMA = t.TABLE_SCHEMA  
where 
    c.`table_schema` = 'MyDatabase'
```

After parsing the information and providing the required Meta-Data-Objects, My header output just looks like this:

```
<?=$db->getColumnMetdata('contractNumber')->getHeader($_SESSION["user_language"]));?>
```

Code in between can vary in complexity. My `ColumnMetadata` also contains other information like `required`, `searchable`, length, possible foreign keys, and much more. That part would be up to you - just for localize headers, an associative Array would work as well. something like :

```
["de"] => {
   "table1.contractNumber" => "Vertragsnummer"
   "table1.Id" => "Id"
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have done my work using the instructions shared by you. This information is really useful for me and it helps me to learn more about information schema and localization. Thank you